# Sonatype Nexus 3.1 UI does not display browse capability with ldap and Rut Auth

Tags: upgrade, nexus, sonatype

I recently upgraded Sonatype Nexus 2.14.1-01 to 3.1.0-04.
After the upgrade, I enabled Rut Auth and configured, checked the LDAP configuration and can connect to LDAP.

However when the SSO login happens - I do see the User ID displayed on the screen, however the browse and search option on the left panel and the admin gear icon are not displayed on the UI. The user logged in has the nx-admin capability.

Note: anonymous access is disabled for this installation. Users are required to login to be able to read/view the repos.

What could cause this?

Comment: If I login using the user id and ldap password the UI displays correctly as well. It's just when the SSO happens, it does not seem to get the privileges pulled from LDAP

Comment: We just found some bugs in this area, follow these issues for updates:  https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-13173 https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-13171